# Установка программы "Антиплагиат"

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как установить на линукс программу "Антиплагиат"?

Comment: Возможно вы имели ввиду не  "Антипладиат", а "Антиплагиат".Вопрос необходимо дополнить, нужно знать какой дистрибутив конкретно у вас.Данная программа есть только под дистрибутив Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

Через wine! Лично пробовал ее устанавливать, но у меня не встала из-за моей лени - обновить NET Framework(wine). На ubuntu wine у меня грызло все. Еще можно узнать к какому типу пренадлежит данная программа, и найти ее аналог под Linux, что облегчит (а в будущем даже улучшит) вашу работу!